# ScrollViewer slow performance with DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, xaml, .net-4.0

I have the following scenario:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
         <!--many other controls-->
         <DataGrid />
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Now, when I bind DataGrid to large amount of data (around 10.000 rows) I am having very slow perfomance. In fact, i get OutOfmemory exception (and I have 8 GB memory)! I read somewhere that this is because ScrollViewer overrides DataGrid virtualisation (or something like that), but I don't know how to prevent that. If I remove the ScrollViewer, problem solved! The data loads in less than a second.

I want to keep the ScrollViewer (because of other controls) and have good performance. Is that possible? If not, is there any other solution-workaround?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A common workaround to these sorts of problems is to add an invisible "sizing element" in the same Row as the `DataGrid`, then you can bind `DataGrid.Height` to the `ActualHeight` of the sizing element. This way, your `DataGrid` will always consume the Height of the `RowDefinition`. Example

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Content="Some Control.." />
        <Rectangle Name="sizingElement"
                   Grid.Row="1"
                   Fill="Transparent"
                   Margin="1"/>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1"
                  Height="{Binding ElementName=sizingElement,
                                   Path=ActualHeight, FallbackValue=1}">
            <!--...-->
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Content="Some more controls etc.." Grid.Row="2"/>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: @Vale: I don't ge it, the outer scroll-viewer does not do anything anymore unless the DataGrid is reduced to a height of 0. Why would you want something like that?

Comment: @H.B.: It can depend on other factors as well. If you have three Rows like Auto, *, Auto and place the `DataGrid` in the middle row with a `MinHeight` of 100 and a Control that can be anywhere from 10 to 1000 in Height in the last row, the outer `ScrollViewer` scrolls the `Controls` if needed and the `DataGrid` `ScrollViewer` scrolls the `DataGrid`

Comment: @Meleak: Hmm, good point. But i can't help but think that there has to be a better way of doing this, i've used actual-size bindings for various things but this seems a bit out of place to me...

Comment: Excellent workaround.  This solved a similar setup I've got that was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 4):

The outer ScrollViewer effectively gives the DataGrid as much space as it likes, that way its height becomes huge, showing all rows at once. Just restrict the DataGrid by explicitly setting a height on it for example.

Comment: Actually, that is not the best solution. If I resize the Window now, DataGrid will not resize.

Comment: @Vale: As i said, that is just an example, you just need to restrict the size, i for one would not place the DataGrid in the ScrollViewer but in one of the grid-cells.

Comment: DataGrid is in the grid cell, but the hole grid is inside the ScrollViewer.

Comment: @Vale: You should only place the ScrollViewer in the grid cells of the other controls.

Comment: Why would I put ScrollViewer inside a cell? I want my hole window to be scrollable, so I put it around the grid. The grid is content of the window.

Comment: How excactly do you expect the DataGrid to resize then if you resize the window? If you have something in a scroll-viewer the content does, per definition not resize as the viewer just shows more or less of the content. Just think for yourself a bit and restrict the DataGrid by any means that suit *your* situation, it's not that hard...

Comment: Actually it is. My whole team is trying to find a solution to this specific problem, and nobody is able to so far. It is not an option to restrict the DataGrid size, it's width and height are not set, so it resizes with the grid cell, which is set to *. ScrollViewer is the content but also without size, so it always fits the window size. We need this behaviour for many projects...

Comment: @Vale: So do you want to have the whole datagrid there so it can be scrolled with the outer scrollviewer but it should be virtualizing its items? If so, i would not recommend it, for one thing the outer scroll-viewer does not care about the column headers so they can be scolled out of view, secondly implementing this to actually virtualize is non-trivial to say the least, so i would not recommend this at all. DataGrids are not mean to be scrolled by external ScrollViewers.

Comment: I actually don't want external scroll viewer to affect my data grid. But at the same time I want the data grid to be inside a scroll viewer. Is that possible?