# Slow performance with WPF DataGrid and ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, performance

I have this style for a data grid:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="DG_ScrollViewer" Focusable="false">
                    <ScrollViewer.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter"
                                                                Grid.Column="1"
                                                                Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>

                                <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter"
                                                        CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}"
                                                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                                        Grid.Row="1" />

                                <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                                           Grid.Column="2"
                                           Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                                           Orientation="Vertical"
                                           Grid.Row="1"
                                           Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                           ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"/>

                                <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                                               Grid.Column="1"
                                               Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                                               Orientation="Horizontal"
                                               Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </ScrollViewer.Template>

                    <Grid>
                        <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                        Grid.Row="0" />

                        <Canvas Width="128"
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                x:Name="Image" />
                    </Grid>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

I know that if you load a lot of data on a data grid, the performance suffers. I can use virtualization to mitigate that performance hit, however, as soon as I throw the grid in a custom scroll viewer, the virtualization is lost.

I am trying to get it back, but I'm not sure how -- while still retain the element named `Image` in my XAML.

Basically, I want to have an image scrolling with the data grid contents and the above code works fine, it's just that I don't know how to enable virtualization. Is it even possible?

**Update:** Looks like I've found a problem. The last `Grid` in the template causes a problem:

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                    Grid.Row="0" />

    <Canvas Width="128"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Grid.Row="0"
            x:Name="Image" />
</Grid>
```

As soon as I take the `Canvas` and `Grid` out, leaving only the `ItemsPresenter`, then it's fast again. How can I get it fast and still retain this `Canvas`?

**Update 2:** How can I apply this ([ScrollViewer slow perfomance with DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7256780/283055)) strategy for my `Grid` shown above? I tried this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Rectangle Name="sizingElement" Grid.Row="0" Fill="Transparent" Margin="1"/>

    <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Height="{Binding ElementName=sizingElement, Path=ActualHeight, FallbackValue=1}" />

    <Canvas Width="128"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Grid.Row="0"
            x:Name="Image" />
</Grid>
```

However, now the scrollbars have disappeared?

I realize that I can't virtualize a `Canvas`, and I don't need to. In fact, the whole `Canvas` gets drawn and I have no logic to separate it into smaller parts. It's completely fine to render the image at its entirety, as long as I can keep row virtualization.

Comment: I was not aware Grid supports virtualization. ¿How are you implementing it?

Comment: I meant DataGrid supports virtualization.

Comment: I recall something about ScrollViewer in DataGrid breaking the DataGrid virtualization but I cannot find it.  Is it read only.  If so give GridView a try - it is much faster.

Comment: @Blam I have no issue with `DataGrid` if I remove my extra `Canvas` element. Therefore, it's not a problem with `DataGrid` per se, and in fact even `ListView` in this scenario is slow.

Comment: @Blam Obviously a scroll viewer causes problems with virtualization because it asks the child to take full height so that the viewer can measure its size and show the scrollbar accordingly, but as soon as the child (data grid) goes full on height, virtualization is gone.

Comment: I missed that you wanted the `Canvas` to be scrollable while keeping Virtualization. You can set x:Name="ItemsPresenter" on the "ItemsPresenter" to get virtualization back but then you won't be able to scroll the `Canvas`

Comment: @Meleak perhaps I can make the Canvas in another scroll viewer and synchronize the scroll position with the data grid scroll viewer's position?

Comment: What exactly is the `Canvas` for?  Can you use adorners instead?  Every `ScrollViewer` implicitly creates an `AdornerLayer`, so it should be trivial to position adorners inside the scrollable area of a `DataGrid`, no custom template needed.

Answer (score 2):

I've got virtualization working for my custom control based on TreeView (.Net 4.0). I modified a little the style to match DataGrid, hope it is going to work for your case:

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
<Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
<Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="True" />
<Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode" Value="Recycling" />
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
<Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                              VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
      <Border x:Name="Border" Grid.Column="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
              BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="2">
        <DockPanel>

            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_Body_Scroll" Background="White" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanContentScroll="True">

              <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                            VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" />

          </ScrollViewer>

        </DockPanel>
      </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that virtualization only works if the contents of the scrollviewer supports IScrollInfo / VirtualizingPanel.

As far as I can see you want to have your items with a canvas with something below it - all inside your scrolling area. Is it actually a special kind of row you want? If so you could go that way and insert a special row instead?
Or you could just move that outside the datagrid - or try using RowDetails - it is not the same apperance I know - but far easiere to use.

To get virtualization to work with what you have your canvas have to be inside the virtualizing panel.