# Slow datagrid - improve performance

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a pretty huge Datagrid.

Here's the datagrid with just one column:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgVarConfig"
              ItemsSource="{Binding VarConfigList, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedVarConfig, Mode=TwoWay}"
              Margin="8,56,557,80"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              CanUserDeleteRows="False"
              CanUserResizeRows="False"
              HeadersVisibility="Column"
              CanUserAddRows="False"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              PreviewKeyDown="dgVarConfig_PreviewKeyDown"
              BeginningEdit="dgVarConfig_BeginningEdit"
              CellEditEnding="dgVarConfig_CellEditEnding"
              SelectionChanged="dgVarConfig_SelectionChanged"
              EnableRowVirtualization="True"
              EnableColumnVirtualization="False"
              VerticalGridLinesBrush="Black"
              VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode ="Standard"
              VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="true">


<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="auto"  MinWidth="150" SortMemberPath="Match_expression">

        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentControl>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource highlightConverter}" ConverterParameter="MATCHEXPRESSION">
                                <Binding Path="Match_expression"></Binding>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </ContentControl>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Match_expression}" FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Style="{StaticResource GridTextBox}"></TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Padding="5 0" Content="Auswahlformel" VerticalAlignment="Center" Cursor="Hand" Foreground="White"/>
                                        <TextBox x:Name="txtMatchExpressionFilter" Margin="0 5" Grid.Column="2" Width="150" Visibility="Collapsed"></TextBox>
                                        <Button Grid.Column="3" Margin="5 0" x:Name="btnFilterMatchExpresion" Style="{StaticResource MyButton}" Width="16" Height="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Click="btnFilterMatchExpresion_Click">
                                            <Button.Background>
                                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/filter.png"/>
                                            </Button.Background>
                                        </Button>

                                        <Path x:Name="SortArrow"
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"                                           
                                        Width="8" Height="6" Margin="2,0,5,0"
                                        Stretch="Fill" Opacity="0.5" Fill="White"
                                        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.4"
                                        Visibility="Collapsed"
                                        Data="M0,0 L1,0 0.5,1 z" />

                                        <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="1" BorderThickness="1" 
                                               BorderBrush="{Binding VerticalGridLinesBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Cursor="SizeWE"/>
                                    </Grid>


                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="SortDirection" Value="Ascending">
                                            <Setter TargetName="SortArrow" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                            <Setter TargetName="SortArrow" Property="RenderTransform">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <RotateTransform Angle="180" />
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </Trigger>
                                        <Trigger Property="SortDirection" Value="Descending">
                                            <Setter TargetName="SortArrow" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>

    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>

<DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <StackPanel Background="Gray" Margin="-5 0 0 0">
                                        <TextBlock Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Name, StringFormat=Gruppe: {0}}" Margin="10 5 0 5"/>
                                        <ItemsPresenter />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>

            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DockPanel Background="LightGray">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Foreground="Black" Margin="10 2 0 2"/>
                            <ItemsPresenter></ItemsPresenter>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
</DataGrid.GroupStyle>

<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem x:Name="cmAddGroup" Header="Gruppe zuweisen" Click="cmAddGroup_Click" ></MenuItem>
    <MenuItem x:Name="cmRemoveDeleteFlag" Header="Löschvermerk entfernen" Click="cmRemoveDeleteFlag_Click"></MenuItem>
    </ContextMenu>          
</DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

Let me explain:

"highlightConverter" checks the value of the cell and does some sort of syntaxhighlighting, syntaxcheck and returns a colored `TextBlock`

If i want to edit that `TextBlock` i had to convert it to a `TextBox`

The grid has two groups (i havent posted all columns, so the groups aren't here, but the `GroupStyle`)

Two have the SortingArrows i added them here too.
On each column Header there is a filterButton to filter the rows.

That leads me to my problem: The grid gets really really slow on filtering, sorting, resize rows/columns, reorder columns, scrolling etc. 
I think its because of the `TextBlock` and `TextBox` items. Is there any better solution to improve the performance?

Here's the HighlightConverter.cs

```
public class HighlightConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public static Dictionary<String, SyntaxResult> calcFormulaCache;
    public static Dictionary<String, SyntaxResult> matchExpressionCache;

    public HighlightConverter()
    {
        calcFormulaCache = new Dictionary<string, SyntaxResult>();
        matchExpressionCache = new Dictionary<string, SyntaxResult>();
    }

    ClientSettings clientSettings = new ClientSettings();

    Brush[] colorArray;

    Regex subFormula = new Regex(@"\w+\(\)");
    Regex sapFormula = new Regex(@"\w+\(([^)]+)\)");
    Regex strings = new Regex(@"\'[^']+\'");
    Regex numerals = new Regex(@"\b[0-9\.]+\b");
    Regex characteristic = new Regex(@"(?:)?\w+(?:)?");
    Regex andOr = new Regex(@"( and )|( AND )|( or )|( OR )");
    Regex not = new Regex(@"(not )|(NOT )");

    VariantConfigurationTestDAO variantConfigurationTestDAO = new VariantConfigurationTestDAO();


    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!clientSettings.SyntaxCheck && !clientSettings.SyntaxCheck)
            return values[0];

        TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();

        string input = values[0] as String;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        {
            if (clientSettings.SyntaxHighlighting)
            {
                colorArray = new Brush[input.Length];

                for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
                    colorArray[i] = Brushes.Black;

                //Reihenfolge beibehalten!!
                assignColor(Brushes.Blue, characteristic.Matches(input));
                assignColor(Brushes.Black, andOr.Matches(input));
                assignColor(Brushes.Black, numerals.Matches(input));
                assignColor(Brushes.Orange, strings.Matches(input));
                assignColor(Brushes.DeepPink, subFormula.Matches(input));
                assignColor(Brushes.Green, sapFormula.Matches(input));
                assignColor(Brushes.Green, not.Matches(input));

                List<Char> splittedInput = input.ToCharArray().ToList();
                int index = 0;
                foreach (Char character in splittedInput)
                {
                    textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run(character.ToString()) { Foreground = colorArray[index] });
                    index++;
                }

                colorArray = null;
            }
            else
            {
                colorArray = null;
                textBlock.Text = input;
            }

            if (clientSettings.SyntaxCheck)
            {
                Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.Red, 3);
                TextDecoration textDec = new TextDecoration(TextDecorationLocation.Underline, pen, 4, TextDecorationUnit.Pixel, TextDecorationUnit.FontRecommended);


                 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty((String)parameter))
                 {
                     String para = (String)parameter;
                     SyntaxResult syntaxResult = null;

                     switch (para)
                     {
                         case "VARIANT":
                             if (para == "VARIANT")
                             {
                                 if (characteristic.IsMatch(input) || subFormula.IsMatch(input))
                                 {
                                     if (andOr.IsMatch(input) || numerals.IsMatch(input) || strings.IsMatch(input) || sapFormula.IsMatch(input) || not.IsMatch(input))
                                     {
                                         textBlock.TextDecorations.Add(textDec);
                                         textBlock.ToolTip = "Hier darf nur ein Merkmal oder eine Subformel stehen";
                                     }
                                 }
                             }
                             break;
                         case "CALCFORMULA":
                             if (!calcFormulaCache.ContainsKey(input))
                                 calcFormulaCache.Add(input, variantConfigurationTestDAO.vcCalculateFormula3(input, true));

                             syntaxResult = calcFormulaCache[input];
                             break;
                         case "MATCHEXPRESSION":
                             if (!matchExpressionCache.ContainsKey(input))
                                 matchExpressionCache.Add(input, variantConfigurationTestDAO.vcEvalMatchEx(input, true));


                             syntaxResult = matchExpressionCache[input];;
                             break;
                         default:
                             break;
                     }


                     if (syntaxResult != null)
                     {
                         if (syntaxResult.syntax > 0)
                         {
                             textBlock.TextDecorations.Add(textDec);

                             if (syntaxResult.errors.Count == 0)
                                 textBlock.ToolTip = "Allgemeiner Syntaxfehler";
                             else
                                 textBlock.ToolTip = String.Join(",", syntaxResult.errors);
                         }
                     }

                 }

                if (values.Count() == 2)
                {
                    string input2 = values[1] as String;

                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input2))
                    {
                        textBlock.TextDecorations.Add(textDec);
                        textBlock.ToolTip = "Es müssen Variante und Kalkulationsformel gefüllt sein";
                    }
                }
            }
        }



        return textBlock;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


    private void assignColor(Brush brush, MatchCollection matchCollection)
    {
        foreach (Match match in matchCollection)
        {
            int start = match.Index;
            int end = start + match.Length;

            for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
            {
                colorArray[i] = brush;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How many rows are you performing this on at any one point in time? Is it noticeably slow performing the highlightconverter on a single row - or is it that this method is being run on all rows?

Comment: i run the highlightconverter on every row. at the moment there are about 100 rows, but in the future there will be a couple of thousand. but the loading isnt the problem at all. i can wait. the problem is the slow scrolling, filtering, resorting, resizing and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my view, it is not a problem of using `IMultiConverter`, but `Virtualization` and `Column Rendering`.

Try to use these properties to your DataGrid:

- Enabled VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode for a Grid
- Set VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="true" for DataGrid
- MaxWidth="2560" MaxHeight="1600"

[Never put a DataGrid in a ScrollViewer, because you will essentially lose virtualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254362/scrollviewer-slow-perfomance-with-datagrid).

For example:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeDataTable, IsAsync=True}" 
          VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="true" EnableRowVirtualization="True"
        EnableColumnVirtualization="True" MaxWidth="2560" MaxHeight="1600"  
        VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"   
        VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"/>
```

Comment: it loads way faster, but its kinda laggy when scrolling vertically

Comment: i dont know what its called in english.. i think stuttering? its slow :D

Comment: the loading is a bit slower with this. but the vertical slow scrolling is gone. horizontal scrolling is slow again :D

Comment: i cant set a fixed column width, there are up do X chars in one column

Comment: @ThomasKlammer try to use this settings to `DataGrid` without using yout IMultiConverter and see the difference about scroll vertically and horizontally

Answer (score 1):

You have rather big `Convert` method. Imagine that it invokes for each cell in your DataGrid.

1. Try to take syntax analysis to another thread. For user it will look like - text entered and in couple of seconds syntax will be checked and/or highlighted.
2. `Regex.Matches` use lazy initialization, so when you are iterating through matches - it actually perform search in string based on regular expression, each time. Try to exclude `assignColor` methods group in `Convert()`and check execution time. If it helps - try to write your own string parser, without regular expressions.
3. In this line `List<Char> splittedInput = input.ToCharArray().ToList();` you are iterating twice through `input` characters. First time - when you are creating array from string characters, and second time - when you are creating list from array items. And then you are iterating again through this string in `foreach (Char character in splittedInput)`. You can actually iterate through `input` itself : `foreach (var character in input)`.
4. In this line: `if (values.Count() == 2)` use `.Length` (property of array) instead of `.Count()` (extension LINQ method), because in each moment of time array knows it's length, and calling extension linq method cause to deal with array like with `IEnumerable` with lazy initialization.

But in my opinion main problem is in consecutive text analysis. Frequent solution is to perform string analysis in parallel thread - for non-pausing user input (or performing any actions on this).